# Motion detector in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app that will detect when a device moves and categorize the movement (up, down, left, right). What framework can I use to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope those links can help you:

[Motion Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)

[Android Gesture Recognition Tool](http://www.dfki.de/~rnessel/tools/gesture_recognition/gesture_recognition.htm)

[How to detect shake motion on Android phone](http://www.clingmarks.com/how-to-detect-shake-motion-on-android-phone/25)

[Android - basic gesture detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Comment: Third link in this answer is dead.

Comment: Second link in this answer is dead.